# Phrase for naming someone/something?

Tags: idioms, formality

I am drawing a blank trying to think of the phrase or verb you use when you name someone or something. Like when you name a child or you name a ship.

Something like:

> I gave him the name "John"

But with a verb or phrase, like:

> I ______ed him "John"

I am looking for a verb like "named" or "called", but with a more archaic feel, like "bequeath" or "bestow", but those didn't sound right to me.

Comment: ........dubbed.

Comment: While "dubbed" would work, when I think of that I think of being "dubbed" a title, such as a hero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking of [christening](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/christen?s=ts) an infant or a ship. The practice originates in the Christian initiation rite of baptism, where a priest/minister asks the father and godparents, "What shall this child be called?" (The mother was usually not present so soon after the birth, but in the Anglican tradition had a brief thanksgiving service called "churching" when she was able to attend worship again.) The father would then answer with what the child's given name was to be.

The notion of naming a child was transferred to newly built ships, which were similarly "[christened](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceremonial_ship_launching)," though after the Protestant Reformation, the naming ritual for ships became a purely secular affair. The practice of breaking a bottle of wine or champagne across the bow began in late 17th century Britain.

Answer (score 0):

Denominated would work. It basically means to give a name to.

> > to give a name to; denote; designate.

(http://www.dictionary.com/browse/denominate?s=t) is where I got the actually got the formal definition.

In your context, you would write; *I denominated him "John"*

Hope this helps!